# Retorno de string vazio - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho uma tabela com uma string e diversos campos separados por | (pipe)

Preciso trazer cada campo em uma coluna. Eu até consegui uma maneira, o problema é que quando um registro não tem o campo preenchido a string traz ||.

Detalhe, **eu não posso alterar a string original.**

Alguém teria uma solução em Oracle SQL ??

Fiz do seguinte modo:

```
CREATE TABLE t_1 ( strings varchar2(4000));
/
INSERT INTO t_1
VALUES ('99|1500001|JOANA PRADO |08227525490|BRA|0||');

INSERT INTO t_1
VALUES ('99|1500002|LUCIANA XIMENES SILVA||BRA|0||');

INSERT INTO t_1
VALUES ('99|1500003|JULIA ROBERTS|44303539805|USA|0||');

COMMIT;

SELECT regexp_substr(strings,'[^|]+',1,1) identificador,
       regexp_substr(strings,'[^|]+',1,2) id,
       regexp_substr(strings,'[^|]+',1,3) nome,
       regexp_substr(strings,'[^|]+',1,4) cpf,
       regexp_substr(strings,'[^|]+',1,5) pais,
       regexp_substr(strings,'[^|]+',1,6) tipo
FROM t_1
```

Reparem que o registro id 1500002 não tem cpf e ai o campo de pais acaba ocupando o espaço do CPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso os campos possam ser vazios:

```
SELECT rtrim(regexp_substr(strings,'[^|]*',1,1),'|') AS identificador,
       rtrim(regexp_substr(strings,'[^|]*',1,2),'|') AS id,
       rtrim(regexp_substr(strings,'[^|]*',1,3),'|') AS nome,
       rtrim(regexp_substr(strings,'[^|]*',1,4),'|') AS cpf,
       rtrim(regexp_substr(strings,'[^|]*',1,5),'|') AS pais,
       rtrim(regexp_substr(strings,'[^|]*',1,6),'|') AS tipo
FROM t_1
```

Basicamente inclui a letra separadora no resultado, e exclui ela depois com `RTRIM()`.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Obrigado.